# create c# class for json string which have number as variables in object

Tags: c#, json, rest, variables, webapi

I have to pass following **JSON** format to the *REST api*.

```
 "weconnect_validate":{
                "Row":[
                    {"0":"44063fe6-fe22-11ea-bb30-005056923098::TEST10800::9888880470","1":"TEST10800"}
                    ]
            }
```

Now problem occurring here is that how i create class for

> Row with variable name 0 and 1.

I have tried following

```
public class BasicRow
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public string Zero { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string One { get; set; }
}
public class Weconnect_Validate
{
    
    public BasicRow[] rows { get; set; }
}
```

but it is not working. In debug mode it is passing

```
Row:[{"Zero":......
```

Please suggest some tricks or different way to create c# class.

**Edit**

Following json object i need to send to REST api using http client .

```
{"PWSESSIONRS":{"PWPROCESSRS":{"PWDATA":{"weconnect_validate":{"Row":[{"0":"dc9a2d38-fe28-11ea-bb30-005056923098","1":"TEST10800"}]}},"PWHEADER":{"LOGIN_ID":"TEST10800","ORG_ID":"HSA","APP_ID":"HSA","IN_PROCESS_ID":"1","OUT_PROCESS_ID":"weconnect_validate"}}}}
```

My question is how to build c# classes for this type of json string or object.

Comment: Are you using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize?

Comment: Maybe you can use a List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>.

Comment: You should be on the right track. Please provide a complete example of what is not working. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @TsahiAsher i am not deserializing  it . I have to send to REST api using httpclient, so i am serializing using Javascript serializer .

Comment: @DavidStania i have just written here part of a complex json object . Using your idea would lead to complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuickType.io suggested this, which is what my first thought was (Array of Dictionary<string, string>) given that your assertion that JsonProperty wasn't working:

```
namespace SomeNamespaceHere
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Globalization;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

    public partial class RootClassNameHere
    {
        [JsonProperty("weconnect_validate")]
        public WeconnectValidate WeconnectValidate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class WeconnectValidate
    {
        [JsonProperty("Row")]
        public Dictionary<string, string>[] Row { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class RootClassNameHere
    {
        public static RootClassNameHere FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClassNameHere>(json, SomeNamespaceHere.Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this RootClassNameHere self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, SomeNamespaceHere.Converter.Settings);
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
}
```

But I didn't actually encounter any problems using your proposed route:

[image]

with this code:

```
    public class Row
    {
        [JsonProperty("0")]
        public string Zero { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("1")]
        public string One { get; set; } 
    }

    
    public class WeconnectValidate
    {
        public List<Row> Row { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("weconnect_validate")]
        public WeconnectValidate WeconnectValidate { get; set; }
    }
```

Used like:

```
        var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Root()
        {
            WeconnectValidate = new WeconnectValidate()
            {
                Row = new List<Row>(){
                    new Row() { Zero = "a", One = "b" },
                    new Row() { Zero = "c", One = "d" }
                    }
            }
        });
```

With the latest Newtonsoft.Json

[image]